# Why does my render in blender look like this?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image]I'm new to blender and have no idea why the render looks like this. Does anyone know how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE. Have you tried searching for any tutorials on how to get started with Blender?

Comment: either you have no light in your scene, or you have a graphic card problem

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)